# Why can't I use setup_postdata($post) in the sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a function that takes one parameter - post type, and will output each posts with some html and title, content etc within that. However, I want to be able to use functions associated with $post, especially the_excerpt. However, when I try to use my function in my sidebar php widget, it simply outputs the main page's title and content, not the custom queries post info.

If I run the function in the page, it works fine though, and echos out the custom queries' post details. You may ask why I don't just put this in the sidebar, well it's too messy and I'll be reusing it with different custom posts, so I thought I'd write a function.

MY function:

```
function myRecentPosts($postType){
 wp_reset_postdata();
   $args = array( 'post_type' => $postType,'posts_per_page' => 3);
   $recentPosts = get_posts( $args );

   foreach($recentPosts as $post){
      setup_postdata($post);  ?>                  
    <article>
      <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
      <?php the_excerpt();?>
    </article>

 <?php 
  }
   wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Comment: can you give the code of how you are calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you chechk dou you have any custom loop in single/home/index or main php file ?

If you have 1 and more loop you use, please add this lines at the and of the loop ..

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```